Hide svg custom cursor over iframe video embed
Similar to this question, but I couldn't make the answers work with my existing code. I have a custom cursor which is an inline svg, it works great everywhere (and scrolls with the page) but gets stuck at the edge of the iframe from a Vimeo embed. I'd like to hide it when the mouse enters the iframe and bring it back when it exits. How can I adjust my code below to make the last part of the JS work correctly?


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let lastX, lastY, lastScrolled = 0;;
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
      lastX = e.pageX - 1;
      lastY = e.pageY - 1;
      $('#cursor').css({
        left: e.pageX - 1,
        top: e.pageY - 1,
        pointerEvents: 'none'
      });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
      if (lastScrolled != $(window)
        .scrollTop()) {
        lastY -= lastScrolled;
        lastScrolled = $(window)
          .scrollTop();
        lastY += lastScrolled;
      }
      $('#cursor').css({
        left: lastX,
        top: lastY,
        pointerEvents: 'none'
      });
    });
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  cursor.style.display = 'none';
})
iframe.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  cursor.style.display = 'block';
})
</script>
body,html { cursor: none !important; }
#cursor {display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 9999; pointer-events:none; 
    width: 1.2rem; height: auto; } 
/*  width: 6.666rem; */
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    * { cursor: default !important; }
    #cursor{display: none;}
}
#cursor .cursorshape {fill: #d9e021;}

.embedvid {position: relative; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%;} 
.embedvid iframe, .embedvid object, .embedvid embed {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.ratio-16-9 {padding-bottom: 56.25%;}
<svg version="1.1" id="cursor" style="width:1.2rem;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 30 38" enable-background="new 0 0 30 38" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon class="cursorshape" points="29.397,31.059 29.397,28.54 29.397,24.939 29.397,22.42 29.397,18.819 29.397,16.3 29.397,10.18 
    0.603,0.822 0.603,6.942 0.603,9.46 0.603,13.062 0.603,15.581 0.603,19.181 0.603,21.701 0.603,27.82 29.397,37.178 "/>
</svg>

<div style="width:50%">
<div class="embedvid ratio-16-9">
        <iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/766323945' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>




You might consider moving this all into CSS, as an inline SVG.


body,
* {
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height="30" width="38" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 30 38" enable-background="new 0 0 30 38" xml:space="preserve"><polygon class="cursorshape" fill="%23d9e021" points="29.397,31.059 29.397,28.54 29.397,24.939 29.397,22.42 29.397,18.819 29.397,16.3 29.397,10.18 0.603,0.822 0.603,6.942 0.603,9.46 0.603,13.062 0.603,15.581 0.603,19.181 0.603,21.701 0.603,27.82 29.397,37.178 "/></svg>') 0 0, auto;
}

.embedvid {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.embedvid iframe,
.embedvid object,
.embedvid embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ratio-16-9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
<div style="width:50%">
  <div class="embedvid ratio-16-9">
    <iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/766323945' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>




Thanks for your answer! This seems great in theory, but the cursor still looks blurry/jagged in Safari. It also doesn't seem to work below the video / over the button. Really looking to keep this as a JS solution, maybe one day the css option will catch up in functionality.
